# How to write unit test for Google Signin functions in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing and want to know is unit test necessary for delegate functions of google signin or facebook signin.
If yes how can one write it?

```
func btnGoogleLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
        startLoader()
        
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        //        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate=self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }
    
    
    func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
        self.stopLoader()
        
    }
    
    // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
              present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
              dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.stopLoader()
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @RohitKale Not yet.